# How to filter data using SQL for between dates

Tags: sql

I am using the following line of code in my SQL query as follows:

where DATE_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_SETUP between '01/03/2021' and '28/02/2022'

Unfortunately the SQL won't run and comes back with "A character string failed conversion to a numeric value"

Can anyone help me with a workaround?
Thanks

Comment: First, use ISO8601 standard formatting for dates... `BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2022-02-28'`  Second, [show us the definition of the table being queried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), so that we can see the datatype in that column. Finally, [specify which RDBMS you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql); SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc?

Comment: first tell us which database you are usinf exactly but every database has a default date type which you should use

Comment: try to cast the string to datetime, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I can not see the column data type in your question but if it is a Datetime or Datetime2 type, you need to use ISO8601 format for your queries.

```
WHERE DATE_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_SETUP BETWEEN '2021-03-01' AND '2022-02-28'
```